# Asp.Net identity does not create Database when using custom User

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Im a little bit confused about `UserManager.Create(...)`.

When I use the Standard EntityFramework's `IdentityUser` to create and add a new User everything works fine. EntityFramework creates a database if none exists with my connectionstring `Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=IdentityDemo;trusted_connection=yes;` and adds a User to the Database.
ExampleProgram:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var username = "ygg";
            var password = "Password123!";

            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            var creationResult = userManager.Create(new IdentityUser(username), password);
        }
```

But when i try to use my own CustomUser, EntityFramework does nothing and i get a NullReferenceException at `UserManager.Create(...)`.

Here is my Extended CustomUser Project:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userName = "Ygg";
        var password = "Password123!";

        var userStore = new CustomUserStore(new CustomUserDbContext());
        var userManager = new UserManager<CustomUser, int>(userStore);

        var creationResult = userManager.Create(
               new CustomUser {UserName = userName}, password);  //<--- Exception Here                     
    }
```

CustomUser-class:

```
public class CustomUser : IUser<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

CustomUserDbContext:

```
public class CustomUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public CustomUserDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<CustomUser> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>();
        user.ToTable("Users");
        user.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        user.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        user.Property(x => x.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And last but not least, CustomUserStore:

```
public class CustomUserStore : IUserPasswordStore<CustomUser, int>
{
    private readonly CustomUserDbContext _context;

    public CustomUserStore(CustomUserDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(CustomUser user)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Exception:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Stacktrace:

> bei Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<UpdatePassword>d__39.MoveNext()
>      bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      bei Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__d.MoveNext()
>      bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      bei Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
>      bei Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Create[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2 manager, TUser user, String password)
>      bei Identity.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\syncplicity\z003apfp\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Identity\Identity\Program.cs:Zeile 21.
>      bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)

I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.0 and AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1

Did i miss anything to configure, so AspNet.Identity and EntityFrameworks accepts my own implementations here?

Any help or thoughts where the problem lies, is appreciated.

I already tried to create the database first and then try to add a User using `userManager.Create(new CustomUser {UserName = userName}, password)`, but this leads also to the same NullReferenceException

Comment: Post the the entire NullRef exception.

Comment: I'm a bit confuse. Do you want ASP.NET Identity to create `Users` table for you, and use that table instead of `AspNetUsers` table?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

When you override something you should do it for the whole structure of Identity.

For example your DB Context should use something like this:

**Custom Context**

```
CustomUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
```

**Custom User**

```
 User : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
```

**Custom Role**

```
 CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole> { }
```

**Custom UserLogin**

```
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
```

**CustomUserClaim**

```
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
```

Note that was an example yous should adapt according to your need.